# How can I get temperature data for each Countries?

Tags: heat-map, data, time

I need maximum and minimum temperature data of each countries.

I searched a lot but could not find the values.

Could you give links if it is possible?

Comment: what do you mean by maximum and minimum. Do you need max/min in time for the average country temperature? or the min and max at a given moment but at different places in the country ? OR ... ?There are so many combinations that further details are needed.

Comment: It is not important which city has minimum or maximum values. I just interested in Countries maximum and minimum temperature data. Seasons are not important too. For example In Turkey  Min : -25 Maximum : 43

Comment: This sounds like a question more suited to the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways that you could possibly achieve this.  My personal favorite is using RSS feeds to pump out the data to url that you can link to.  WeatherBug has a great RSS feed that you can customize and setup for each country you want to then pass the values to a page, email, whatever you like.

Here is the starting point for the RSS. you can get other examples and code snippets from this site as well.
http://weather.weatherbug.com/support/rss.html

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for replying but I need annual temperature data. I forgot to say. This site unfortunately gives daily data.